# Pivot_wider is giving a lot of N/A values when reshaping

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to use the pivot_wider function on the PARAMETER column to get out the unique values however, when I do that, it gives me a bunch on NA values. Below is the code that I am trying to use so far but it is resulting in the picture below and I have attempted a lot of na.omit related functions which just removed all rows.

```
  pivot_wider(names_from = PARAMETER,
              values_from = Month_Average)
```

I am trying to get it in the below format: where everything is on one row.

| Year | Month | LAT | LON | Temperature | Humidity | wind_10_meters | wind_50_meters | precipitation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | Sep | 25.5 | -90 | 95 | 24 | 8 | 8 | .5 |
| 1991 | Oct | 25.5 | -90 | 89 | 20 | 8 | 4 | 1 |

These aren't accurate numbers, but I want to get all the information to show for that year and month in one row? Below I have provided the data that I am working with.

Here is what **dput()** gave me. I did head() since it was really long.

```
structure(list(PARAMETER = c("PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS"
), YEAR = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L), LAT = c(35.25, 
35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25), LON = c(-71.75, -71.75, -71.75, 
-71.75, -71.75, -71.75), ANN = c(101.91, 101.91, 101.91, 101.91, 
101.91, 101.91), MONTH = c("NOV", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", 
"MAY"), Month_Average = c(101.9, 102.01, 102.22, 102.36, 101.87, 
101.63)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

dput of the code after running my pivot_wider:

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L
), LAT = c(35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25), LON = c(-71.75, 
-71.75, -71.75, -71.75, -71.75, -71.75), ANN = c(101.91, 101.91, 
101.91, 101.91, 101.91, 101.91), MONTH = c("NOV", "JAN", "FEB", 
"MAR", "APR", "MAY"), PS = c(101.9, 102.01, 102.22, 102.36, 101.87, 
101.63), T2M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), RH2M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), WS10M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), WS50M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), PRECTOTCORR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Adding Parameter test

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L
), MONTH = c("APR", "APR", "APR", "APR", "APR", "APR"), LAT = c(35.25, 
35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25, 35.25), LON = c(-78.75, -78.75, -78.75, 
-78.75, -78.75, -78.75), ANN = c(2.93, 3.42, 5.39, 16.89, 75.28, 
101.13), number_of_parameters = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    YEAR = 1990L, MONTH = "APR", LAT = 35.25, LON = -78.75, .rows = structure(list(
        1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Please let me know if I need to include any more information!

Comment: please also paste the `dput()` of the current output

Comment: Never share links to images of the output, you should share formated code for the output instead. Either paste the printed console output or   `pivot_wider(data, names_from = PARAMETER,
              values_from = Month_Average) |>dput()`

Comment: @GuedesBF I have edited the post to include the current output dput(). Thank you for the tip on the images!

Comment: @Damian I ran the unique function and it seemed to only contain character variables.

Comment: Oops, I'm going to delete my comment, as I realize I made a mistake. Nevertheless, the long data doesn't contain all of the data shown in the pivoted data (probably because you intentionally only included a portion as it is so long) so it is a little bit of guesswork. Does each Year| |Month| |LAT| |LON| combination contain measurements from all of the parameters? Perhaps some of them are missing?

Comment: @Damian No, there seems to be a value for each parameter. It seems to me when pivoting it is showing the PS first and when that row is created the rest of the row (the other variables) are given NA because they did not have a value on that row before? Not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: Last thing - check there are 6 parameters for each time point/location -`data %>%
  group_by(YEAR,MONTH,LAT,LON,ANN)%>%
  summarize(number_of_parameters = length(PARAMETER))`. `number_of_parameters` should equal 6 for all rows.

Comment: @Damian I ran the code you sent and it gave me this.

Comment: Try running on all of your data rather than only the `head()` and `dput` output you show here.

Comment: @Damian Hey, not sure I am understanding what you are asking for? I ran that previous code on my whole data set and then did dput(head(df)). I also did a filter to see if there were any parameter < 1 or > 1 and 0 where less than and about 288 rows were greater than.

Comment: Your initial pivot_wider result would suggest there are missing "T2M","RH2M"   
"WS10M","WS50M","PRECTOTCORR" values from those particular timepoint/locations. For each time point/location, there should be 6 measurements - "T2M", "RH2M","WS10M", "WS50M", "PRECTOTCORR" and "PS" (anything missing will be `NA` ). Running my code on all data will count the number of parameter values at each timepoint/location (which should be 6). If you `%>% filter(number_of_parameters <6)`  you will find those timepoint/locations are missing 1 or more parameter values (although not identify which parameter(s)).

Comment: @Damian That makes sense and do you think the NA values are coming from me using the Month_Avg column since they are all being split using those values and maybe the ones that are taken for T2M get removed and result in a Na section for the other ones?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes - your wider table assumes there will be a `Month_Average` value for each `PARAMETER` at each time point. Any missing `Month_Average` value will return an `NA`.  FYI, you can still use your pivoted table with `NA` values present for many calculations (but you might need to add additional arguments to account for this) .

Comment: @Damian Perfect I was able to fix the problem with this information! Thank you!